# Can you dynamically cast during runtime inside a linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq

Hello is there a way to dynamically cast inside the following code so I do not need a bunch of if statements with nearly identical code?

```
        List<DateTime> dateTimeList = null;

        if(_dataSeriesList[0].GetType().Name == "Class1")
        {
            dateTimeList =
                _dataSeriesList.ConvertAll(x => (Class1) x)
                    .Where(d => d.Time >= min && d.Time <= max)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Time)
                    .Select(d => d.Time)
                    .ToList();
} 
else if(_dataSeriesList[0].GetType().Name == "Class2")
{
                dateTimeList =
                _dataSeriesList.ConvertAll(x => (Class2) x)
                    .Where(d => d.Time >= min && d.Time <= max)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Time)
                    .Select(d => d.Time)
                    .ToList();
}
.
.
and so on
```

I tried using the following code:

```
    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }

Type t2 = _dataSeriesList[0].GetType();

dateTimeList =
                _dataSeriesList.ConvertAll(x => castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { x }))
                    .Where(d => d.Time >= min && d.Time <= max)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Time)
                    .Select(d => d.Time)
                    .ToList();
```

But then the linq statement will not compile.

Comment: Don't `Class1` and `Class2` have a common base class or a common interface where the relevant members exist?

Comment: You can't really cast to a type decided at at runtime, even if you invoked the `castMethod` using reflection it's return type would be object anyway.

Comment: Instead of `ConvertAll<>` instance method on `List<>` you should use Linq's `Select<,>` method. Just change `ConvertAll` to `Select`. Another possibility is the `Cast<>` method.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example exhibiting your use case rather than this abstract one? Setting aside the fact that `DateTime` can't have child classes, the general answer here would be that you would have to be able to cast the values into _some_ common base class in order to do anything like what you are describing.

Comment: @Hogan The compiler generates classes for anonymous types, unsuprisingly it does this at compile time.

Comment: @Rawling - fair -- my comment was wrong I deleted it.

Comment: They do share a base class but that base class does not contain the DateTime Time property.  Class1 and Class2...and so on are auto generated classes.  So I couldn't easily move the properties into the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't share a common base type you can do it like this:

```
 dateTimeList = 
    _dataSeriesList.Select(x => { 
        if (x.GetType().Name == "Class1") 
          return ((Class1)x).Time;
        else
          return ((Class2)x).Time;
                   })
                 .Where(d => d >= min && d <= max)
                 .OrderBy(t => t)
                 .Select(d => d)
                 .ToList();
```

Since all you are doing is working with the time element you just select out the item of interest according to your rules and then use it in a common way.

Of course if what you are working with is more complicated you select that information instead.

This is fairly standard in Linq -- make a new type on the fly that you need in order to do your work.

((as has been pointed out in the comments "on the fly" is actually determined at compile time and not dynamic in the typical use of the word))

Comment: I didn't think there was a way to avoid using if / switch statements but I think the way you have this is the best way.  Thanks for your aid!